# E: Package 'gccxml' has no installation candidate

Tags: xml, gcc, installation, package, candidate

[image: screenshot of terminal]

So, I am unable to find *gccxml* in ubuntu18,hep me download *gccxml* in *ubuntu18*. *castxml* is easily available. But I need *gccxml*. Also what is *installation candidate*? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GCC-XML home page](https://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) says:

> Note: GCC-XML has been succeeded by [CastXML](https://github.com/CastXML/CastXML#readme).

CastXML [has been packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=castxml&searchon=sourcenames&suite=all&section=all).  However, the replacement is based on the LLVM toolchain.

You could try to compile GCC-XML yourself, but since it was apparently based on GCC 4.2 (released in 2007), it is a dead end, especially for processing C++ sources.

Comment: I have done my work using castxml, thanks @Florian Weimer !!